# String Matching on large dataset in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, fuzzywuzzy

I have a dataset with approximately 3000000 rows .The data comprised of column such as customer_pincode,customer_state,customer_city,customer_address,customer_name.Now I have to find people living on the same address by getting approximate match of the address.For that I have grouped the data on the basis of pincodes after that I have fetched numbers from the address string and then again grouped data based on the numbers after that created a meshgrid of all address number-wise and then taking fuzz.token_sort_ratio with each entry. But this process is taking too much time approx 7-8 days. How can I make it work faster.I am using pandas alongwith fuzywuzzy for fuzz ratio.

Comment: hi, it's because of meshgrid function that you are using, in my opinion. try to find common values and try to use merge instead of meshgrid

Comment: It is just address data. how can I find common values in that.